# I have a problem in Laravel daily log file permission error

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm using the Laravel daily log file, and sometimes I get the following error. However, I've added the `permission` attribute in the logging file.

> The stream or file laravel-2021-08-02.log could not be opened in append mode: chmod(): Operation not permitted

```
'daily' => [ 
    'driver' => 'daily', 
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'), 
    'level' => 'debug', 
    'days' => 7,
    'permission' => 0664 
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your old `laravel.log` file has the same permission. `'permission' => 0664` this will work for future log files.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'll check the laravel.log file and try as you mentioned hope it works fine.